# Set of functions with same Lipschitz constant attains a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, arzela-ascoli

Let $E$ be the set of all functions $u : [0, 1] \to R$ such that $u(0) = 0$ and $u$ satisfies
a Lipschitz condition with Lipschitz constant $1$.

Define φ : E → R according to the formula:

$$
\phi(u) = \int_0^1 (u(x)^2 - u(x)) dx
$$
Prove that there exists a function $u \in E$ at which $\phi(u)$ attains an absolute
maximum

---

Here's what I know:

The Lipschitz condition implies that the functions $u$ are equicontinuous

Arzela-Ascoli implies that the set $E$ has a convergent subsequence.

The fact $u(0)=0$ screams out to me that I need to use the Fundamental Thm of Calculus

But other than that, I'm really unsure how to begin.

Comment: You can interpret your problem within this context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003766/show-that-the-set-of-uniformly-lipschitz-functions-vanishing-at-0-is-compact-i

Comment: Still no help on this?   Let $C[0,1]$ be the Banach space of continuous real-valued functions equipped with the sup norm.  Check that the map $\phi:C[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ defined here is continuous.  Check that the set  $E\subset C[0,1]$ defined here is compact (using Arzelà–Ascoli as you say).  At that point you are pretty well done since this is the same situation as in the calculus for continuous functions on a compact interval.